# How to convert a large dataframe based on columns into a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a large dataframe with 1365 columns as shown in the example:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(7.48, 7.59), Y1 = c(49.16, 48.70), ID1 = c("B_1", "B_1_2"), TI1 = c(191.31, 1349.93), 
              X2 = c(8.15, 8.06), Y2 = c(48.40, 48.18), ID2 = c("B_1", "B_1_2"), TI2 = c(191.39, 1349.97),
              X3 = c(8.80, 8.87), Y3 = c(47.65, 47.20), ID3 = c("B_1", "B_1_2"), TI3 = c(191.48, 1350.05))
```

now I would like to split this dataframe into a list of dataframes (i.e. three dataframes in this list; 12/4 = 3). the expected list that looks like as follows:

```
dflist[[1]]

X1    Y1     ID1     TI1   
7.48  49.16  B_1    191.31
7.59  48.70  B_1_2  1349.93

dflist[[2]]

X2     Y2    ID2     TI2 
8.15   48.40   B_1    191.39
8.06   48.18   B_1_2  1349.97

dflist[[3]]

X3     Y3    ID3     TI3
8.80   47.65   B_1    191.48 
8.87   47.20   B_1_2  1350.05
```

and I would like to rearrange (in ascending order) the data in each dataframe of the list based on column 4 of each dataframe

first to convert the dataframe into list, I used the following code but not working

```
n <- seq(1,12, by = 4)

my_data <- list()
for (i in 3) {
  for (j in seq(1, 12, by = 4)) {

    my_data[[i]] <- df3[, j:j+3]

  }
}
```

for sorting the list the following code is used:

```
dflist1 <- lapply(dflist, function(1){
            1[with(dflist, order[, 4]), ]
           })
```

looking for the code to get the expected output (dflist) as presented above

Comment: Would a stacked dataset with each of the original 'datasets' also be an acceptable output? If so, you could just reshape like `reshape(df, varying=TRUE, sep="", direction="long")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `split.default` to divide data into list, use `lapply` to loop over each element and `order` them based on 4th column.

```
dflist <- lapply(split.default(df, gl(ncol(df)/4, 4)),function(x) x[order(x[[4]]),])
dflist
#$`1`
#    X1   Y1   ID1  TI1
#1 7.48 49.2   B_1  191
#2 7.59 48.7 B_1_2 1350

#$`2`
#    X2   Y2   ID2  TI2
#1 8.15 48.4   B_1  191
#2 8.06 48.2 B_1_2 1350

#$`3`
#    X3   Y3   ID3  TI3
#1 8.80 47.6   B_1  191
#2 8.87 47.2 B_1_2 1350
```

Comment: I am getting the error as follows " Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default"

Comment: @Kumar Sorry there was a misaligned bracket in there. I have updated the answer, can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse solution: use `map`, `select`, and `arrange_at`.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(as.character(1:3), ~select(df, ends_with(.x)) %>% arrange_at(4))
```

Explanation:

- `map` iterates over the elements in the first argument - here, string representations of 1, 2, 3.
- Those elements are applied to the function call in the second argument, which is `select`, a column-selection method from `dplyr`.
- On each iteration of `map`, the columns that are selected are those that `end_with` 1, then 2, then 3.
- Once that subset of columns is created, we `arrange_at` the 4th column.
- `map` returns a list of outputs from the function, which here are data frames - and that gets you your list of sorted, subsetted, data frames.

Comment: i have the dataset that has the column names as same i.e. X, Y, ID, TI, X, Y, ID, TI, X, Y, ID, TI. for the column names having same, the posted code is not working and resulting an error as " Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
In addition: There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)"